# Bootstrap Sidebar Expanding Subcategories

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

Using [this as a my starting template](http://www.bootply.com/render/100983). I am attempting to integrate the bootstrap way of having expanding subcategories as seen on the sidebar of the [getting started page of getbootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/).

However, I am having an issue where I am scrolling through the page and if I get to the category or its sub-category it highlights all parts of the category in the sidebar (instead of just the subcategory).

Here is the snippet of my sidebar HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-3" id="leftCol">
<ul class="nav nav-stacked" id="sidebar">
    <li class="active">
        <a>User Guide</a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#intro">Introduction</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#search">Searching</a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#searchresults">Search Results</a>
                <a href="#understandingsearch">Understanding Search Results</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#profile">User Profile</a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#viewprofile">Viewing a Profile</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#eventgraph">Event Graph</a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#graphdisplay">Graph Display</a>
                <a href="#graphinteraction">Graph Interaction</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#infopanel">Information Panel</a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#paneldisplay">Panel Display</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
body {
    padding-top:50px;
}

#masthead {
    min-height:250px;
}

#masthead h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 1;
    padding-top:20px;
}

#masthead .well {
    margin-top:8%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #masthead h1 {
        font-size: 50px;
    }
}

.navbar-bright {
    background-color:#111155;
    color:#fff;
}

.affix-top,.affix{
    position: static;
}

@media (min-width: 979px) {
    #sidebar.affix-top {
        position: static;
        margin-top:30px;
        width:228px;
    }

    #sidebar.affix {
        position: fixed;
        top:70px;
        width:228px;
    }
}

#sidebar li.active {
    font-weight: bold;
    border:0 #CC0000 solid;
    border-right-width:5px;
}

/* Nav: second level */
#sidebar .nav {
    display: none;
}

#sidebar > li.active .nav {
    display: block;
}

#sidebar .nav {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

#sidebar .nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    font-size: 90%;
}
```

I have also included the JSFiddle to show what I am seeing: http://jsfiddle.net/HsZ9q/8/

Please note, in the JSFiddle you have to expand the window to as big as possible till you see the sidebar due to responsiveness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your css add a border to the `<li>` element when it's :active you should do it to the `<a>` element. Also on the submenu each element has to be on a `<li>`

Hope it helps

http://jsfiddle.net/HsZ9q/12/

```
#sidebar li.active > a{
    font-weight: bold;
    border:0 #CC0000 solid;
    border-right-width:5px;
}

<!--left-->
<div class="col-md-3" id="leftCol">
    <ul class="nav nav-stacked" id="sidebar">
        <li class="active">
            <a>User Guide</a>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#intro">Introduction</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#search">Searching</a>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#searchresults">Search Results</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#understandingsearch">Understanding Search Results</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#profile">User Profile</a>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#viewprofile">Viewing a Profile</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#eventgraph">Event Graph</a>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#graphdisplay">Graph Display</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#graphinteraction">Graph Interaction</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#infopanel">Information Panel</a>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#paneldisplay">Panel Display</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div><!--/left-->
```

Comment: This seems to be the correct fix however I am noticing that when scrolling through the content it isn't highlighting at the correct points, however, if you click on it in the sidebar it goes to the correct start of the content. Would you happen to know what the cause of this is?

Comment: it's working fine here on Chrome under Ubuntu OS, also firefox

Comment: Hmmmm it appeared to be a glitch when I first looked at it but now it looks fine! Thanks!